# Android-compiler can't find meta data even though it is exist in the manifest file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to run Google Cloud messaging system , logcat shows me that the
metadata is should include android name and android value, which is already 
exist inside the manifest

```
3016-3016/com.icanappz.gcmimplementation E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL   EXCEPTION: main


 Process: com.icanappz.gcmimplementation, PID: 3016
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.icanappz.gcmimplementation/com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 6171000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 6171000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.D(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
        at com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
```

that was the logcat and this is the mainfiest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/icanTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.DailogeNotice"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.CustomeWebView"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.PreferenceActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />





        <receiver
                android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service     android:name="com.icanappz.gcmimplementation.GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you calling google_play_services_version value from integers.xml of your project?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't get the error message. It says:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your
>   app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected
>   6587000 but found 6171000.  You must have the following declaration
>   within the  element:

and the

```
expected 6587000 but found 6171000.
```

is crucial here. It simply means that you built your app againsy newer version (6587000) than you got installed on the device/emulator (6171000) you tried to run the app on.

I got also some fears that you got incorrect code that deals with this situation as you should be telling the user about this and asking to upgrade instead of crashing. In fact, you should take a look at [GooglePlayServiceUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html) class, especially [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) and properly deal with returned codes doing:

```
if( GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError( errorCode ) ) {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, null, requestCode)
}
```

whenever **user recoverable** error occured includes:

```
ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED
ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING
ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED
ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID
```

Comment: The error seems to happen when calling _isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()_ .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this meta data into your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `<application>`:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and you will not have problems getting the correct Google Play Services version.

Answer (score 1):

**Most likely you don't take the JAR from your "dependenced" project.** Therefore, the JAR and the Google project are on different versions if one of them gets updated. The error you get in LogCat is TOTALLY misleading.

*How to solve?*

Add the .jar from /libs/ folder of the "real" `google-play-services_lib` project (either from your workspace or directly from /sdk/extras/google/..., depending on how your workspace/project setup) so it can compile its new jar from there.

After updating stuff in SDK manager, your error appeared on my screen and it took me 3 hours to figure this out and I will now take another 30 minutes explaining to people how to fix it and posting it under everyone's question.

I hate Android.